# Locking a Relative Reference inside a Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a search that when found will input a formula into a cell.
The problem is trying to create a formula that will reference the row that the search is found (`OffSet`?) and locking it inside the formula (Same as using <kbd>F4</kbd> or `$` outside of VBA)

```
Set SrchRng = Range("F6:F30")

For Each cel In SrchRng

    'SL Events
       If cel.Value = "SL" Then


       I = "=RC[-9]-R6C4"
       ''''I want it to be along these lines
       ''''I = "=RC[-9]-$R$C[-9]"                      or
       ''''I = "=RC[-9]-($Cel.Offset(, -9).Value)"


              cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = I

        End If
```

The second cell needs to be locked because I'm using auto fill on a different part of the macro.

Can this be done?

Comment: The use of `$` for locking only applies in `A1` mode. In `R1C1` mode a reference can look like `R1C1`, `R[1]C1`, `R1C[1]`, or `R[1]C[1]`. The `[` & `]` indicate a relative reference, but if they are not there then it is an absolute (or locked) reference.

Comment: And formulas should be assigned to cells using the `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` property - it isn't a good idea to use the `.Value` property for a formula (although it usually works).

Comment: I understand that the `[ ]` make it relative referencing  and without them it becomes absolute referencing. 
I just need a solution to lock the relative reference for later when I use auto fill to pull that formula down inside the worksheet.

Comment: @excelnoob - You can't lock a relative reference. You need to compute the absolute reference before you assign the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `=RC[-9]-R6C4` uses the `R1C1` reference style.

This style uses numbers for both the rows and columns (i.e. `R?C?`). The Cell References are represented in relation to the cell containing the formula.

***Absolute References*** are declared by the numbers to the right of the `R` for rows and `C` for columns (`R6C4` equals to `$D$6`).

***Relative References*** are declared by a number within square brackets, a negative number indicates the cells above\left for rows\columns to the cell containing the formula, while a positive number determine the cells below\right for rows\columns (`C[-9]` indicates nine columns to the left of the cell with the formula). Another form of relative reference is when the R or C appear without a number beside, meaning it refers to the same row\column of the cell containing the formula.

From the above to ensure that in the formula `=RC[-9]-R6C4` (i.e. `=D6-$D$6`) the second cell always refers to the same row of the found cell `cel` just need to replace this line:

```
I = "=RC[-9]-R6C4"
```

With this line:

```
I = "=RC[-9]-R" & cel.Row & "C4"
```

Thus making the row fix and to Always refers to same row of the cell `cel`

Comment: Perfect answer!! I'm sure there are many other ways to solve the same problem but this was simple and easy to apply to my prior code. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to lock a cell for a further use of AutoFill, you'll have to use A1 reference style.

For a reminder (said in comments), you can't use `$` to lock something in a formula using R1C1 style.

```
Sub Test_Excel_Noob()
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim CelRg As Range

    Set SrchRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("F6:F30")

    For Each CelRg In SrchRng.Cells
        'SL Events
        If CelRg.Value <> "SL" Then
        Else
            '''Equivalent of "=RC[-9]-$R$C[-9]" 
            '''which is incorrect as you can't use $ in R1C1 style
            CelRg.Offset(0, 7).Formula = _
                "=" & CelRg.Offset(0, -2).Address(0, 0) & _
                "-" & CelRg.Offset(0, -2).Address(1, 1)
        End If
    Next CelRg
End Sub
```